# How to show both detailed and aggregate data in one Tablix in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am developing a report in Visual Studio 2013 and report requirements are:

Report should include detailed data for each provider who provides individual services to patients
Report also should include records for providers who provide group services. Thus the criteria in this set is different than the first set
Report should include both #1&#2 in one report separated by each provider
I created #1 & # 2 reports but I am stock how to bring them together in one report where each provider gets his/her individual as well as group services reports in one nice formatted report. I have tried subreport with no avail but looking into linked report. Any thoughts/suggestion how this can be done? here is an example
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your data for both the Individual and Group Services is similar so what I would do is have one query for all data and then use grouping in a table to break it up the way you want and let SSRS do the work.

If your data isn't combined already in one query, I would UNION the two queries. You may need to add some dummy columns to match them all (for instance, your **Group Services** might need a column of **ClientID** - `'' as ClientID`) and another column with the type (`'Group Services' as ServiceType` in **Group** query and `'Individual Services' as ServiceType` for **Individual**).

For your table, you would have 2 detail lines (add a second by right clicking on the line  - one for Group Services with it's fields and the other for Individual Services. Use **Visibility** to hide them (`=ServiceType ="Group Services"`)

Then Add Group -> Parent Grouping for **ServiceType** then Add Group -> Parent Group for **Provider**. Then just add your group totals.